Fresh !J5 installation on shared hosting keeps going to index.html
Fresh Joomla 5.1.x PHP 8.2.18 installation on friend's Hostmonster.com shared webhost. System info says "WebServer to PHP Interface    litespeed"
After installation, plain domain name URL sends site to [domainname]/index.html and throws a 404 error (page not found). Disabling both settings just outputs the whole path to the same nonexistent index.html. There is no index.html file in the webroot.
The .htaccess file is default and unchanged. I then uncommented RewriteBase / but made no difference. Also, tried to comment out Options +FollowSymlinks but that didn't work either.
Then tried to add Directory index.php but that didn't work either.
Then tried a redirect but that didn't work either.
So, it seems if I disable .htaccess it works fine but I lose the SEF. Is there an issue with .htaccess?
Please help.

Please edit your question to include your complete .htaccess file. “Disabling both settings” - disabling what settings exactly? “if I disable .htaccess” - what do you mean by “disable” exactly? Are you removing or renaming the “.htaccess” file? Or are you literally disabling .htaccess file processing in the server config?

I always make a copy of htaccess.txt then rename it .htaccess. If I delete .htaccess or rename it to .htaccess_BAK it is disabled.

Here is the file. The "RewriteOptions inherit" command is inserted by the webhost. Makes no difference if it is there or not.
https://www.coderstool.com/cs/4hMJT2

Also, the webhost says they have this issue with Wordpress and they do the same...disable .htaccess. Sounds really weird and wrong to me.

UPDATE: Webhost created new .htaccess with only this code at the top and it worked but without SEF. As soon as I add in the Joomla .htaccess code it goes back to redirecting to index.html.
https://www.coderstool.com/cs/D1z2kK
I created an info.php file and to my surprise mod_rewrite does not exist.
So, debugging by process of elimination. I opened a fresh .htaccess file and only added the # RewriteOptions inherit command.
Didn't work.
Then commented out everything except the code snippet from above.
It didn't work.
Then commented out RewriteOptions inherit. IT WORKS!
Then started to uncomment everything else. In the SEF section, when I uncommented RewriteEngine On it stopped working again despite the snippet to provide alternate if mod_rewrite is not active.
So, I think I am going to pull another ticket with webhost and have them check into enabling mod_rewrite.
